# Analytics firing on AJAX by default?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get Google Analytics Site Search to work but our search is #-based and not ?-based, meaning the parameters are not being picked up.

I want to intercept the url sent to GA and replacing the # with ?, but I am surprised to see that our AJAX calls are already going to GA on every search.  Where is this behaviour coming from - does GA automatically bind to AjaxComplete by default?  How could I pull off my intercept then?

Comment: GA doesn't track AJAX by default, so maybe you should provide a link or example with more information.

Comment: If I check Firebug I can see GA being called on my AJAX calls (it's a search page).  I'm investigating our in-house framework to see if this is our behaviour or GA's.

Comment: It looks like GA is doing this by default - I can't see anything to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other approach is to use the search and replace filter in Google Analytics.

jQuery address is rewriting the url `/Search#reg=term` to `/Search/reg=term`

We use the search string `^\/Search\/` with a replacement string as `/Search?`

Answer (score 0):

The update on AJAX call is being done by jQuery, not GA.  Useful.

The workaround for my problem is to use an extra instruction with _setAllowAnchor, which instructs GA to treat # as ?.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking

We found the solution here:
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/02/04/setallowanchor/